# Flutter Flame ScaleDetector doesn't work when a Component with DragCallbacks is added

Tags: flutter, scale, draggable, scaling, flame

How can I make **scale** and **drag** gestures work **simultaneously** in Flutter Flame? I want to have draggable components placed on the zoomable board. Imagine you have a puzzle board and you want to zoom in to be able to drag the smaller pieces with precision.

DragCallbacks is taking over all touch inputs even when they happen outside of the Component. I see under the hood that whenever a Component with `DragCallbacks` is added `ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer` is registered as one of the [gestureDetectors](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/dac2ebbf506ff48ca8f34d872bbc47cba3ad6c7b/packages/flame/lib/src/game/game.dart#L35) ([here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/dac2ebbf506ff48ca8f34d872bbc47cba3ad6c7b/packages/flame/lib/src/events/flame_game_mixins/has_draggable_components.dart#L169)).

How can I make scale and drag work together? Is there a way to manually propagate touch events when they happen outside of my component?

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flame: ^1.8.1
```

```dart
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame/palette.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScaleDragGame extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaleDragGame({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final game = ScaleDragFlameGame();

    return GameWidget(game: game);
  }
}

/// `onScale` methods are not called when a Component with DragCallbacks is added as a child.
/// Green rectangle can be dragged around but scale gestures don't work. But if I remove DragCallbacks from
/// [DraggableRectangle] scale gestures start to work.
class ScaleDragFlameGame extends FlameGame with ScaleDetector {
  late final CameraComponent cameraComponent;
  late double startZoom;

  ScaleDragFlameGame();

  @override
  Color backgroundColor() => Colors.yellow;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final world = World();
    cameraComponent = CameraComponent(world: world)
      ..viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.center
      ..viewport.anchor = Anchor.center;
    addAll([world, cameraComponent]);

    world.add(DraggableRectangle(
      size: size / 4,
      position: size / 6,
      paint: BasicPalette.darkGreen.paint(),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void onScaleStart(ScaleStartInfo info) {
    startZoom = cameraComponent.viewfinder.zoom;
  }

  @override
  void onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateInfo info) {
    /// not called when Component with DragCallbacks was added

    final currentScale = info.scale.global;
    if (!currentScale.isIdentity()) {
      final newZoom = (startZoom * currentScale.y).clamp(1.0, 6.0);
      cameraComponent.viewfinder.zoom = newZoom;
    } else {
      final delta = info.delta.game;
      cameraComponent.viewfinder.position.translate(-delta.x, -delta.y);
    }
  }
}

/// Remove [DragCallbacks] and see that pinch-to-zoom gestures start working
class DraggableRectangle extends RectangleComponent with DragCallbacks {
  DraggableRectangle({
    super.position,
    super.size,
    super.paint,
  });

  @override
  void onDragUpdate(DragUpdateEvent event) {
    super.onDragUpdate(event);
    position += event.delta;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a good question, it's not easily possible currently since scale is a super-set of pan in Flutter, so we'd have to use scale detection under the hood to do drags to make this possible and I'm not sure if we'd be able to detect multi touches properly if we did this.